# Does .NET MAUI provide windows overlay feature?

Tags: .net, overlay, fullscreen, maui

Does .NET MAUI provide  windows overlay feature ? I have searched and read many blogs but could not find answer.

Comment: Are you asking if the whole window can be semi-transparent? Because that wouldn't be meaningful on mobile platforms, "No" (it won't be "built-in" to Maui). However, you can do desktop-specific features within the `Windows` folder of your project. On Windows, Maui targets `WinUI 3`. So if its a feature supported by WinUI, you likely can write similar code (in Windows folder) to manipulate the Window that is showing Maui content.

Comment: Thank you Steve,  I am trying to achieve full screen and always on top functionality in my MAUI project .  Since I could not do full screen and always on top on windows so  I was trying to  show my app page over other apps for  android app .During the app is running, I want no other app can appear on top of it.

Comment: What are you trying to prevent? User can always switch to another app..

Comment: Stop and think; if your app can display over other apps, then other apps will be able to display over your app. Instead of telling us what solution you want to use, [tell us what problem you're trying to fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Hi Dour High Arch, I am trying to achieve "Always on top" feature in my MAUI project so user can not pull other app if our app is running. For ex. I have trivia for users but do not want them to google it for answer. Hope it make sense now what I am trying to find solution for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on iOS, but I don't see a corresponding ability on Android.  Modal windows in general (which is how it's done on iOS) are broken on Android.  To see details about doing this with iOS, check out this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/platform-specifics/page-presentation-style.

Comment: That will display *over your OWN app*. This question is about displaying *over ALL apps*. "Always on top" window. A concept that does not exist in mobile OSes.

Comment: Google maps uses this concept when switching to another app during navigating on Android.